# Google sheets formula doesnt work until creating a new sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was using a simple sumifs function in Google Sheets.
All of the cells are working properly in the begining
After a while, some of the sumifs cells starts to be broken, saying "The argument must be a range" with no change in the formula at all. Some other cells remains working.
Formula like e.g.

```
=sumifs(Transaction!D2:D101,Transaction!B2:B101,"GOOGL",Transaction!H2:H101,"",Transaction!C2:C101,"HSBC")
```

It is weird when I copy the same literal formula in other empty cell, it starts working again.
Some I create a new sheet and copy all the cells to the new one and it becomes normal again

Anyone tried before?Any possible explanation to this weird situation?

Comment: your error message means that the specified range does not exist. When you copy the formula to other cells - does the range notation change? Can you provide a sample spreadsheet reproducing this issue?